# Is it possible to change log destination for Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, logging, task-scheduler

I'm not sure if this is the right place for me to ask but I was wondering if it is possible to change where Task Scheduler store its logs? I have an .aspx that can read log files from virtual directories that are stored in IIS. I want to add the task scheduler log to my aspx page like I do with the other log files but I don't want to add a virtual directory to C:\WINNT (where it is currently logging to) because of just me being paranoid. If it is not possible to change the log destination then I will be able to find a workaround. This could possibly be a question for any windows platform in general but I am running my log files from a Windows 2000 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:**

The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

Reference [Changing the log file location](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/schedlog.htm)

> The Log file path can be altered in the registry, if you want the log
>   to be maintained in a different folder or drive. To do so, perform
>   this:
>
> ```
> Click Start, Run and type Regedit.exe
> Navigate to this location:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ SchedulingAgent
>
> Backup the key to a file.
> Double-click the LogPath value in the right-pane
> Type the full path and file name. For example:D:\Logs\SchedLgU.Txt
> Close Regedit.exe
> ```
>
> Then, re-start the Task Scheduler service using these two commands.
>
> ```
> Click Start, Run and type CMD
> Type these commands one by one and press Enter
>
> NET STOP SCHEDULE
> ```
>
> Now, move the SchedLgU.txt file from %Systemroot% to the new location,
>   if you want to preserve the old file and entries.
>
> ```
> NET START SCHEDULE
>
> EXIT
> ```

Comment: When I restart the Task Scheduler service, would it restart all of my scheduled tasks right away or at the time intervals that they are set to?

Comment: No idea off the top of my head :/ I can try and find out later ( tomorrow)

Comment: It's fine. I was able to setup IIS so that the virtual directory that points to C:\WINNT can only be accessed from within my .aspx file. Thanks for the quick answer!